# Side by side image comparison in Linux

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, zooming

Is there any way to view and compare images side by side with the ability to zoom and pan on one image and get the same view on another image (synced views)?

In Windows this can be done using [FastStone Image Viewer](https://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Images-in-FastStone-Image-Viewer). I am looking for the same feature in Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *Geeqie Image Viewer*:

1. Install it with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install geeqie
   ```
2. Open Geeqie
3. Navigate to folder with your images
4. Select *View -> Split -> Horizontal* (or *Vertical*) then open first image on first part and second image on second.

---

Or you can install FSIV under Wine. It [works great](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5647) here.